# Why would the Aen Elle try to have children with Ciri if she's a witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

Apparently at one point the Aen Elle tried to [have a child](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Ciri) with Ciri in an attempt to control the Elder Blood:

> [Avallac'h] explained to her that she had to 'pay the debt' referring to the perceived loss to the Aen Elle when Lara Dorren took Cregennan of Lod as her lover. The elves believed that the latter had 'stolen' Elder Blood from them by marrying Lara. To atone for that 'crime' Avallac'h wanted Ciri to beget a child with Auberon Muircetach, the king of the Aen Elle.
>
> ...
>
> In Tir ná Lia Ciri finally met Auberon, who many times tries to conceive a child with her, however he could not - to him she was just a human, a being of no interest for an Aen Elle. Nevertheless, he was very proud and refused to admit it. Eredin suggested using a 'potion' which would improve Auberon's performance and allow him to conceive a child with Cirilla.

On the other hand, Ciri is a witcher, and witchers are infertile. So the attempt seems futile from the beginning.

Why would the Aen Elle attempt to do so regardless? The only explanation I can think of is that they were not aware that Ciri is a witcher, but that seems improbable given that they know Ciri has the Elder Blood.

Comment: :/ She was only trained by witchers. Even if they still had a way to "transform" her, they wouldn't do it because 1) She was a girl 2) She was a Source.

Comment: @Mithoron are you sure she's not a witcher? The linked article also says her profession is "witcher".

Comment: She was called a witcher, but it was just training, she had her own powers.

Comment: @Allure Please be aware that Witcher Wiki is a mix between canon (the books by Andzej Sapkowski), the games (mostly true to canon but a spin-off with their own lore) and the various movies/TV series (loosely based on canon). One possible ending in the game Witcher 3 is that Ciri picks up the witcher trade, so that's probably why it says that her profession is witcher.

Comment: @Amarth do you mean Ciri attempts to become a Witcher in spite of not undergoing the mutations? Isn't that very dangerous and will get her killed?

Comment: @Allure The most important part seems to be knowing the monster lore and she got that covered. She also got excellent combat training - Vesemir is supposedly the greatest sword master of the whole Continent. Her reflexes are exceptional even without the mutations - at one point she deflects a crossbow bolt with her sword - something that Geralt was also able to do, but unlike Ciri he has gone through the trials. And then there is her unique magic abilities as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: there's the *profession* witcher and the *race* witcher.

Ciri was just *trained* as a witcher, she never went through the final trials that turns one into a witcher through mutations. After surviving the mutations, a human turns into a witcher which is essentially a race of their own. Only a third who go through the trials survive. Besides, the knowledge of how to perform them has been lost since an attack on Kaer Mohren many decades before the main story occurs.

Upon completing the mutations, witchers get improved reflexes, stopped/slowed ageing, improved senses and better nightvision. As a side-effect they turn infertile.

Since Ciri never went through the trials, she's not a witcher. Not a fully-trained one either, since she was only trained during ~3 years or so but the training takes at least twice that time.